# how this kind of erlang gen_server should be tested?

Tags: erlang

I have a gen_server which exports a function like this:

```
my_function(Param) ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, {forward, Param}).
```

and has an handle_cast like this:

```
handle_cast({forward, Param}, #state{peer=Socket} = State) ->
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, Param),
    {noreply, State}.
```

In most of cases the peer that is connected using gen_tcp will reply with one among different messages, and I handle the reply in the handle_info

```
handle_info({tcp, Socket, Data}) ->
    io:format("Received : ~p~n", [Data]),
    {noreply, State}.
```

Is there any recommended way to test this kind of scenario in erlang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setup/teardown functions in order to do something like that:

```
my_test_() -> {
    setup,
    fun() -> my_server:start_link() end,
    fun(_) -> my_server:stop() end,
    fun() ->
        %% here you do all the message sending and such
    end
}.
```

You also need to export a stop/0 function which will be responsible for call/cast the gen_server in order to stop it.

You can find out more infos on fixtures [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Fixtures)

HTH,
Alin

Comment: i know about fixtures, but the problem is that i have experience only with gen_server:call where the return is somehow fixed. How can i relate the data sent using the function to the result obtained in handle_info?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you want to send messages that way that they'll be processed by handle_info ?

Comment: no, once the message is sent in the handle_cast using sockets, i will handle the reply in the handle_info since the reply will come via socket

Comment: Basically what you want to know is how to test if the data was successfully processed by the right piece of code (here, gen_tcp:send) ? Or your question is: "How to test async interaction ?" ?

Comment: I hope this helps you: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/erlang-programming/HxsMDBVMmAA